# Accessing nested static enum method from object instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, pdfbox

I want to write a unit test for the following method I wrote, which uses `PDFBox`:

```
public static PDPageContentStream createWriteablePage(PDDocument document)
        throws IOException
{
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    return new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
}
```

However, I'm unable to find a way of testing it. The `PDPageContentStream` object [has exclusively void return methods](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html), and the hashcodes of the object constantly change (I assume due to metadata when the relevant objects are generated), so I can't use that.

The only approach I can think of is to use a variable located in a nested class inside of the object I'm testing. Inside of the `PDPageContentStream` class is a [nested static enum](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.html) that has the following structure:

```
public static enum AppendMode {
    OVERWRITE,
    APPEND,
    PREPEND;

    private AppendMode() {
    }

    public boolean isOverwrite() {
        return this == OVERWRITE;
    }

    public boolean isPrepend() {
        return this == PREPEND;
    }
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
PDDocument testDocument = new PDDocument();
PDPageContentStream contentStream = createWriteablePage(testDocument);

assertTrue(!contentStream.AppendMode.isOverwrite());
assertTrue(!contentStream.AppendMode.isPrepend());
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not really, the parameter only means where the content stream is inserted. So after the file is created, that property is lost. A more valid test would be to compare the complete content stream, or the rendered page.

Comment: Indeed, if you want to write unit tests, you should first consider what you want to test. Considering the name of your method, `createWriteablePage`, you probably should test whether you now have a *page* you can *write to*. E.g. you can in your test add some text drawing to the returned `PDPageContentStream` and close it, then save the document, read the saved document, apply text extraction, and check whether the extracted text is identical to the text you originally wrote to the page.

Comment: What you could do to get some inspiration is to download the source code, go to the pdfbox subproject, and then look at the tests there, search for PDPageContentStream. To do a rendering test, search for usage of "TestPDFToImage"  usages.